# remote debug read log from remote project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

i use remote debug in eclipse  to connect remote server.

the script is `java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=60016,server=y,suspend=y  -jar positioning-terminal-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

my local system is windows and debug remote the project which is in linux system by eclipse.

but the project log is not print in my local console, still print in its log file so it's difficult to

read which number of line is thrown exception.so how can i look the stack exception in my eclipse

console?

the remote log is like that

```
2014-10-15 10:25:37 [NioProcessor-3] INFO  [com.compass.position.terminal.handler.device.t808.T808Decoder:710] -  t808 receive msg：[7E0102002001355934823907DD46324233463031453937323444343332423335413439333530444641454141411C7E]
2014-10-15 10:25:37 [NioProcessor-3] INFO  [com.compass.position.terminal.handler.device.t808.T808CodeUtils:91] -  t808 convert message begin ：[7E0102002001355934823907DD46324233463031453937323444343332423335413439333530444641454141411C7E]
2014-10-15 10:25:37 [NioProcessor-3] INFO  [com.compass.position.terminal.handler.device.t808.T808CodeUtils:132] -  t808 convert message end ：[0102002001355934823907DD46324233463031453937323444343332423335413439333530444641454141411C]
=====47=====false
2014-10-15 10:25:37 [NioProcessor-3] INFO  [com.compass.position.terminal.handler.device.t808.T808Decoder:130] - =============msgid : [1, 2]
messageReceived
2014-10-15 10:25:37 [NioProcessor-3] INFO  [com.compass.position.terminal.handler.ServerHandler:137] - Received:[F2B3F01E9724D432B35A49350DFAEAAA, act=AUTH, loginDevice=LoginDevice[dt=T808, sn=4067533], response=com.compass.position.terminal.handler.device.t808.T808Response@5d9e4d25]
2014-10-15 10:25:37 [NioProcessor-3] ERROR [com.compass.position.terminal.handler.dealer.ReceiveDealer:86] - 不支持的业务类型:AUTH
2014-10-15 10:25:43 [NioProcessor-2] ERROR [com.compass.position.terminal.logic.InstructService:84] - error-instruct:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't see the remote  console out put in eclipse

use ssh to login into the system

```
ssh username@<ipaddress>
tail -f <logfile>
```